# Wrong keyboard mappings

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, 21.10, function-keys

Yesterday i made the switch to Ubuntu, but sadly not without issues.

I've got a laptop with a pretty standard keyboard, everything works just fine except the
<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys excluding <kbd>F5</kbd>. 
For example <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> should bring my brightness down, but it fullscreens the window instead, on the other hand when i press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> it just pops out "P".

I'm very new to Linux, but i have absolutely no idea whats going on, I've already checked my keyboard layout in settings many times, but it looks exactly like mine, yet the outputs are not what they should be.

Any idea on what i can do to fix this?

Laptop model - Lenovo V15-IIL 
Ubuntu version - 21.10

Comment: Please edit your question to add your laptop model and Ubuntu version. I assume it all worked as expected in windows on the same laptop?

Comment: Yes, everything works fine when i start the laptop on windows, i forgot to add, that i have both operating systems on the laptop